# Node.js - How can i invoke a method inside a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to create a service on NodeJS that executes an integration - at this moment all I have is an initialize function and another called execute.

But, I can't invoke the "execute" function inside "initialize" function, how can I do it?

Thanks in advance,

---

I've tried already:

- Use `this.execute();`
- Use `SchedulerService.execute();`
- Use `execute();`
- Use `var _this = this;` and `_this.execute();`
- Use execute as a parameter inside `scheduleJon(..., function(execute){`

---

```js
import schedulerConf from '../../config/scheduler';
import request from 'request';
import schedule from 'node-schedule';
import dateformat from 'dateformat';

let interations = 0;

const SchedulerService = function(){

    return {

        initialize: async () => {
                console.log(`***** Starting Scheduler on ${dateformat(new Date(), "dd-mm-YYYY h:MM:ss")}`);
                var j = schedule.scheduleJob('*/1 * * * *', function(){
                console.time('Scheduler execution time');
                if(interations === 0){
                    console.log(`Setting scheduler runtime to full time.`);
                }
                interations++;
                SchedulerService.execute();
                console.log(`Job executed ${interations} times.`);
                console.timeEnd('Scheduler execution time');
            });

        },

        execute: async () => {
            var options = {
                url: 'http://example.com',
                method: 'GET'
            }      
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                request(options, function (error, res, body) {
                    if (!error && res.statusCode == 200) {
                        console.log
                        resolve(JSON.parse(body));
                    } else {
                        reject(error);
                    }
                });
            });    
        }
    }
}
export default new SchedulerService();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function returns the other functions, this means the function should run before you can access the internals.
Which means you can call it like so.

```
SchedulerService().execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot call `this.execute()` because when you use arrow functions the `this` keyword refer to the enclosing function context, that is not the object context (that is what you're looking for).

In order to do that you have to use plain functions.

```
return {

        initialize: async function() {
                console.log(`***** Starting Scheduler on ${dateformat(new Date(), "dd-mm-YYYY h:MM:ss")}`);
                var j = schedule.scheduleJob('*/1 * * * *', function(){
                console.time('Scheduler execution time');
                if(interations === 0){
                    console.log(`Setting scheduler runtime to full time.`);
                }
                interations++;
                // call the method
                this.execute();
                console.log(`Job executed ${interations} times.`);
                console.timeEnd('Scheduler execution time');
            });

        },

        execute: async function {
            var options = {
                url: 'http://example.com',
                method: 'GET'
            }      
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                request(options, function (error, res, body) {
                    if (!error && res.statusCode == 200) {
                        console.log
                        resolve(JSON.parse(body));
                    } else {
                        reject(error);
                    }
                });
            });    
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you define your `execute` function outside of the `return` statement that should do the trick.

```
import schedulerConf from '../../config/scheduler';
import request from 'request';
import schedule from 'node-schedule';
import dateformat from 'dateformat';

let interations = 0;

const SchedulerService = function(){

    const execute = async () => {
            var options = {
                url: 'http://example.com',
                method: 'GET'
            }      
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                request(options, function (error, res, body) {
                    if (!error && res.statusCode == 200) {
                        console.log
                        resolve(JSON.parse(body));
                    } else {
                        reject(error);
                    }
                });
            });    
        }

    return {

        initialize: async () => {
                console.log(`***** Starting Scheduler on ${dateformat(new Date(), "dd-mm-YYYY h:MM:ss")}`);
                var j = schedule.scheduleJob('*/1 * * * *', function(){
                console.time('Scheduler execution time');
                if(interations === 0){
                    console.log(`Setting scheduler runtime to full time.`);
                }
                interations++;
                execute();
                console.log(`Job executed ${interations} times.`);
                console.timeEnd('Scheduler execution time');
            });

        },

        execute
    }
}
export default new SchedulerService();
```